# How to find a list of all program heaps on Windows?

Tags: c++, memory-management, win64

In trying to experiment with stack vs heap allocations in a C++ test program, I was first surprised to discover that Windows does not necessarily situate the stack at high addresses and heap at low addresses. On digging deeper, I was further surprised to discover that it maintains *several* heaps, the details about which can be ascertained programmatically as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/getting-process-heaps). So I have now in my test program (on Win10, x86-64, mingw73_64):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // [GetProcessHeaps code copy-pasted here from the MS link above]
    // . . . 
    // . . .

    int* ptr = new int[64];
    qDebug("int array malloc addr in main() = %p", ptr);
    delete [] ptr;

    // New type that does nothing interesting other than debug prints in ctor/dtor
    Foo* pf = new Foo();
    qDebug("Foo malloc addr in main() = %p", pf);
    delete pf;

    return 0;
}
```

[The `qDebug` is a Qt function, not relevant to the present problem.] I had expected both allocations to get fulfilled from one of the program heaps. Instead I see the following:

```
Num heaps = 3
Heap 0 at address: 0x750000 - 0x777000, size 159744 bytes
Heap 1 at address: 0x10000 - 0x20000, size 65536 bytes
Heap 2 at address: 0x1c0000 - 0x1c8000, size 32768 bytes

int array malloc addr in main() = 0x1c64b0

Foo alloc addr in main() = 0xc673920
```

As you can see, the int array allocation gets fulfilled from Heap 2, but the Foo allocation is out in left field somewhere. (Heap sizes obtained from code [here](https://j00ru.vexillium.org/2016/07/disclosing-stack-data-from-the-default-heap-on-windows/).) Repeated runs yield different addresses, but the results are similar (have also seen *both* allocations come out of the "fourth heap"). Are there yet more heaps beyond the three printed by the MS code? Is there another method to get a comprehensive list?

Comment: Welcome to Crazytown. Memory management is <expletive deleted>ing weird. I haven't looked into how this works at the OS level but don't be surprised if you find your stacks are coming from what Windows calls a heap.

Comment: Heck, sometimes you get memory only to find that you didn't *really* get memory. The OS rubber-stamped the request and will do what it can to provide actual physical memory later when you actually try to use it.

Comment: Heaps are not required to occupy contiguous memory.

Comment: @user4581301 I actually did print out stack addresses as well (although didn't include that in my question) via `SIZE_T stackObject; SIZE_T stackBottom = (((SIZE_T) &stackObject) & ~0xfff);` which prints for e.g. `0x6af000` for the stack bottom, and addresses of various stack variables are `0x6afc90`, `0x6afc8c` and so on. So the _stack_ addresses seem consistent (and don't overlap with any of the addresses for the heap mallocs).

Comment: @RaymondChen Right, but the ranges for the individual heaplets must be contiguous, right? I have extracted those via `VirtualQuery()` into a `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION ` struct and then printed out the `mbi.RegionSize`.

Comment: @dqbydt You could step into the `new` calls and see what your particular CRT does in each case.

Comment: No, a single heap can be discontiguous.

Comment: @dxiv that's a good idea. I tried it, and my environment (QtCreator + mingw) did not let me step into the `new` calls - but it doesn't matter: to my surprise I discovered that if ever I break into the program and then run it through, _all_ allocations become sensible again (i.e. map into one of the known heaps)! The "off-piste" addresses disappear! This is far more abstruse than I had imagined, haha

Comment: @RaymondChen well I'll be damned. I'm just going to throw my hands up in the air then :)